# Data warehouse creation on Fact table with Dim tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse

I'm trying to understand the logic on how dim tables are connected with Fact tables.

I currently have a fact table that has no data and have two Dim Tables that have data.

Dim Table 1 : Suburbs

Dim Table 2 : Restaurants

As Dim table have different number of rows. How do I make the Fact table link the Dim table with the suburbs and Restaurants that shows the correct order/results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Fact table is holding facts or numerals.
- Dimension table is holding dimensions or aspects about the facts.

> The data stored in fact, determines the granularity of the facts.
> The granularity of facts decide the granularity of dimension tables.

> E.g., Suburbs is a dimension : Holds the suburb details
> Restaurants is a dimension : Holds the Restaurant details
> FactRestaurantSales is a Fact : Holds the sales at Restaurant granularity level.

1 Pizza of $20 dollars were sold in a restaurant Pizza Garden in suburb Bellevue, will be stored as below:

DimSuburb:

```
+-------------+------------+
| DimsuburbId | Suburbname |
+-------------+------------+
|          1  | Bellevue   |
+-------------+------------+
```

DimRestaurant:

```
+-----------------+----------------+
| DimRestaurantId | RestaurantName |
+-----------------+----------------+
|              1  | Pizza Garden   |
+-----------------+----------------+
```

DimItem;

```
+-----------+----------+
| DimItemId | ItemName |
+-----------+----------+
|        1  | Pizza    |
+-----------+----------+
```

FactRestaurantSales :

```
+-----------------------+--------------+-----------------+---------+-------------+----------------+
| FactRestaurantSalesId |  DimSuburbId | DimRestaurantId | DimItem | DollarSales | QuantitySales  |
+-----------------------+--------------+-----------------+---------+-------------+----------------+
|                   1   |          1   |              1  |      1  |          20 |            1   |
+-----------------------+--------------+-----------------+---------+-------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Venkataraman :), but in a case where you have a lot of numbers and different amount of rows how does dimension table connect with the fact table without checking each and every nook if the table are really matching?

E.g DimItem have 30 Pizzas in Item Name but out of the 12 pizzas the suburbs are different. In this case is there a way I can connect it without checking each individual pizza/suburb?

Comment: @Zafear, consider POS machine. The transaction happens there to OLTP system. From OLTP system, data flows into OLAP system, generally for reporting purpose.  The sale item check first happens in dimension tables, before insertion happening in Fact table. Eg. out of 30 pizza types, one of the type is being sold for 5 quantities, say Cheese Pizza (Item No. 2) and then insertion happens for DimItemtypeId as 2, and quantity as 5 in the Fact table.